# Rename python file but Pylance not finding instances and refactoring?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to rename a python file and want to have all the import instances updated with as well.

Based on the below link, there should be a pop up window every time I rename a file and Pylance will find all the instances and ask to refactor:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense

However I am not getting this pop up window at all... does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Are you actually using Pylance? You might be using Jedi instead — or even no language server, but I think that's unlikely.

Comment: Hi, I just checked the settings - Pylance is selected.

Comment: Me too. All of a sudden, VSCode 1.83.1 on Windows 10 won't pop up this module renaming window and no preview panel afterwards. Reinstalling VSCode won't work. Deleting `%APPDATA%\Code` and `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode` and restarting VSCode won't work. Even downgrading to 1.81.1 won't work. But the instance of VSCode 1.83.1 on macOS Sonoma works just fine. I have no idea at all.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this is a bug of Pylance extension for VSCode on Windows platform.

I've tested with VSCode 1.83.1 on Windows 10 and the following Pylance version.

**Won't work:**

```
Pylance v2023.10.21 (pre-release)
Pylance v2023.10.20
Pylance v2023.10.11 (pre-release)
```

**Module renaming works:**

```
Pylance v2023.10.10
Pylance v2023.9.31 (pre-release)
Pylance v2023.9.30
```

If you absolutely need the [module renaming](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_rename-module) functionality on VSCode for Windows, stick to Pylance v2023.10.10 until there is a new version which fixes this bug. See: [How to install previous versions of extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_install-previous-versions)

Answer (score 1):

I submit [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4964) to github. And now this bug has been fixed in pre-release version 2023.10.31.

You can switch to pre-release version in extension store to solve it.